# Slice and Map an array in Javascript but not seeing sliced array appear

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dom, slice, use-state

> I have an array of saved items that I am passing into my component. My goal is to have just two of them display at the top of the page with a "view one more" button next to them that when clicked, will display an additional item from the array, and so on and so forth.

> I am using an useState hook to accomplish this, as well as slicing and mapping the array of saved items.

> However, I cannot see any of the array elements appear in the DOM.

> When I console.log the array, I can see the entire array in the console, so I don't feel that it's a props problem.

> I am not sure where to go from here or what the exact problem is.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getGames } from '../../actions/game';
import SingleGameMetrics from './SingleGameMetrics';

const FeaturedMetrics = ({ auth, getGames, game: { games } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getGames();
  }, [getGames]);

  const [itemCount, setCount] = useState({
    itemCount: 2,
  });

  // Method
  const generateMoreMetrics = () => {
    setCount({
      itemCount: itemCount >= games.length ? itemCount : itemCount + 1,
    });
    console.log(games);
  };
  return (
    auth.isAuthenticated &&
    auth.loading === false && (
      <div>
        {games.slice(0, itemCount).map((game) => (
          <SingleGameMetrics key={game._id} game={game} />
        ))}
        <button onClick={(e) => generateMoreMetrics(e)}>View More +</button>
      </div>
    )
  );
};

FeaturedMetrics.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getGames: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  game: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  game: state.game,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGames })(FeaturedMetrics);
```

> It is being passed into the Parent Component like this:

```
<FeaturedMetrics />
```

> Does this need anything else like

```
<FeaturedMetrics game={game} /> ?
```

Comment: I'm confused by your comments that logging `games` logs the entire array, but then later you say you aren't passing any props. Can you clarify? FWIW I don't see any overt issues with your code snippet. What debugging have you tried already?

Comment: @DrewReese so I partially fixed my issue. I had some trouble pinpointing the exact issue but now I feel like I better understand what was happening before. However, I am still stuck.

I changed my useState hook to look like this:

`const [itemCount, setCount] = useState(2);`

Before the "ItemCount" was an object so it wouldn't change. 

I've changed my method to look like this:

`const generateMoreMetrics = () => {
    setCount({
      itemCount: + 1,
    });
    console.log(itemCount);
    console.log(typeof(itemCount));
  };`

Now my counter doesn't increase on click.

Comment: Please do update your question with any new details/information about what is working and where you're stuck or having issues.

Comment: @DrewReese I figured it out. Inside my hooks I had itemCount as an object inside {} when it should have only been inside paranthesis and as a number.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem was I had itemCount as an object inside of my inital useState hook, as well as my setCount method with {}, rather than only needing ().

> Incorrect:

```
const [itemCount, setCount] = useState({
    2
  });
```

> Solution:

```
const [itemCount, setCount] = useState(
    2
  );
```

> Incorrect:

```
setCount({
      itemCount + 1,
    });
```

> Solution:

```
setCount(
      itemCount + 1,
    );
```